# Getting multiple checkbox value using Angular10

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

**app.component.html**

```
<form #x="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input [(ngModel)]="details.a" #a="ngModel" type="checkbox" value="1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">HELLO A</label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input [(ngModel)]="details.b" #b="ngModel" type="checkbox" value="2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">HELLO B</label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input [(ngModel)]="details.c" #c="ngModel" type="checkbox" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">HELLO C</label>
        </div>

<button [disabled]="!x.valid" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

**App.Component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
details:{
    a:boolean,
    b:boolean,
    c:boolean
} = {
    a:null,
    b:null,
    c:null
}
constructor(){
}
submit(){
    console.log(this.details) //to get true or false if checked
 }
```

I'm trying to get the status and the value of the checkbox , I need to assign the value to variable if checked

**EXAMPLE:**

if 1 and 3 are checked
var x = 1 + 3
x = 4

Answer (score 0):

Here Object.keys(details) will give you the name of keys present in your object as array (as ["a" , "b" , "c"];

So we have the array , now we use a map function which is same as for loop (i indicates the index) , x indicates the first item of the array so on the first run x will be equal to "a"(as a is the first value of Object.keys(details) . Now we will check whether the first key in object contains value or not by if(details[x]) which will be same as details["a"], so if the value is true we add  i+1 to the total (as i starts from 0)

```
 let total = 0
    Object.keys(details).map((x,i)=>{
    if(details[x]){
     total = total + (i+1)
    
    }
    
    })
```

Comment: Thanks you but I'm new to angular could you be specific

Comment: Hii Faizal I tried this code but it returns undefined

Comment: @FaizalHussain, to loop over an array use `forEach`, `map`is to transform the array

Answer (score 0):

The Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  details: Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', boolean> = {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false
  };

  public get xNumber(): number {
    const numbermap = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
    return Object.entries(this.details)
      // get only the entries with true value
      .filter(([_key, value]) => value)
      // map the keys having true to an array of numbers
      .map(([key]) => numbermap[key])
      // requred for preventing error from reduce if none selected `[].reduce()`
      .concat(0)
      // sum the numbers with reduce
      .reduce((prev = 0, curr) => prev + curr)
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.xNumber);
  }
}
```

The Template:

```html
<form #x="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input
          id="detailsA"
          name="a"
          [(ngModel)]="details.a"
          type="checkbox" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="detailsA">HELLO A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input
          id="detailsB"
          name="b"
          [(ngModel)]="details.b"
          type="checkbox" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="detailsB">HELLO B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input
          id="detailsC"
          name="c"
          [(ngModel)]="details.c"
          type="checkbox" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="detailsC">HELLO C</label>
    </div>

    <button [disabled]="x.invalid" >
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

[This example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-saisht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: how can I get both true or false and the value by this method I can get only the value

Comment: @Casaper, you needn't use `[ngModelOptions]`. This is used **only** when you're working with Reactive Forms (when the input with ngModel is inside a `<form [formGroup]="form">`)

Comment: How can i get if the checkbox is true or false now , I need both of them

Comment: @Ashwin the details properties a, b and c are updated live. They always contain their current state in boolean. Look at the stackblitz example I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-saisht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Eliseo The question was asked with Forms, not ReactiveForms. Angular has so far not marked the ngModel forms as deprecated or anything. I personally also prefer ReactiveForms, but I'm not to tell the OP what to chose.

Comment: @You can not undestand me, I mean that you can remove the `[ngModelOptions]`

Comment: @Eliseo yeah, you're right. I was mistaken. Removed it from the stackblitz example and will remove it here. Sry, and thanks for telling!

Comment: @Casaper how can I assign this value to variable